# Does Axapta 4.0 have a functionality to map data between different tables

Tags: axapta, x++

I have two tables Cashdisc and Convertterm, Does axapta have a functionality where Convertterm.code can be related to CashDisc.Code so that whenever converterm.code changes it can be updated in CashDisc.Code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  I think you're referring to a table relation.

If you want a table to update another table, you can do that through code, but I think you're talking about how the table naturally functions with table relations.

See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190076(v=ax.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom code on Convertterm update method after super to update the Cashdisc table.
If you create table relation in child table and if you set validate property to yes, then you can restrict child data creation without a parent record.